# Programmatically update AzureVPN profile

Tags: azure-vpn

We run a split-tunnel VPN, and route all IP addresses from the [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) document through the VPN. This document (could) be updated weekly, and we'd like to automate the setup for new users.

We already have a pipeline that generates the XML file for the [AzureVPN Client App](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NP355QT2SQB?rtc=1&hl=en-gb&gl=GB)... Is there a way to programmatically update the profiles?

`Get-VpnConnection` (including `--AllUserConnection`) doesn't return anything when connected, so no go from that angle.

In the LocalState folder for the AzureVPN application (`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.AzureVpn_<some_rando_hex>\LocalState`) though, there is a `rasphone.pbk` file which can be viewed in plain text, and seems to contain the profile files added to the application. However, it seems like the customroutes added to the profile are encoded, and looks as follows:

```
ThirdPartyProfileInfo=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I'm assuming this is the IP Address and mask encoded somehow. Anyone know how to decode, and maybe generate a pbk file from an AzureVPN profile file?

Comment: This article (https://www.readandexecute.com/posts/deployazurevpnwithintune/) mentions that it's possible to modify the pbk file, but doesn't explain how to edit the `ThirdPartyProfileInfo` entries.

Comment: As per the note section under[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-p2s-advertise-custom-routes#forced-tunneling), Routing internet traffic over Azure VPN is not supported. what is your end goal/requirement?

Comment: It is supported if you use Azure Firewall and VWAN.